# Sql Server 2008 R2 Full text Search Queries with numerals not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database set up in a SQL Server 2008 R2 Express instance. We have Full Text Support enabled. One of the Tables "Employees" is Full Text Indexed. There is a Column "Address" which is indexed too.

There is a value for the column as follows: "Los Angeles 9"

When we query it by the following:

```
Select * from Employees Contains (Address, '"Los Ang*"'))
```

It fetches the row correctly

But when we query it by the following:

```
Select * from Employees Contains (Address, '"Los Angeles 9*"'))
```

Nothing is fetched

```
 Select * from Employees Contains (Address, '"Los Angeles*" AND "9"'))
```

Also fetches none.

I added a new stoplist to the storage section for my database and added just a cursory stop item, thus excluding the removal of numerals from indexing..

But even after this the above mentioned queries fetched a naught.
Then, I loaded the system default stoplist, removed the numbers 0 to 9 from it, ran the population again.
Still nothing is being fetched...

Is there anything more to be done??
Pls advise.